# " a child growing up in two cultures" equals to "a child who grew up .../who had grown up..."?

Tags: present-participles

> As a child **growing up** in two cultures, I found this difference a bit confusing.

Does the present participle (bold text) equal to "who grew up" or "who had grown up”？ My reasoning is because of the absence of tense for present participle, it can be transformed into multiple different tenses.
If that is right, I am wondering whether I should understand the present participle as "who grew up" or "who had grown up," because there are clear distinctions between "who grew up" and "who had grown up."

And I think I could even say "growing up" is equivalent to "who was growing up"?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "as a child growing up in two cultures" sets the perspective in the past, when the speaker was a child, growing up.

If it said
"As a child who grew up in two cultures, I found this ..."
that might refer what to what the speaker felt when they were a young adult, who had grown up like that, but was no longer a child.

The present participle refers to what was present at a previous time, and it can't be taken  to mean another tense.

Comment: But is it true that there is an absence of tense for present participle, since it is basically an infinite verb, it may take any tenses

Comment: I would say it can be used of a situation set in any time, as determined by the rest of the sentence. It's odd to say that "it may take any tenses". For example, one can say "I was thinking", "I had been thinking", "I will be thinking".